# Why did Pazuzu not possess Regan after Damien got killed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-exorcist

At the end of *The Exorcist*, when Father Damien got possessed and killed himself, why didn't Pazuzu enter Regan's body again?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Bible, suicide is a mortal sin. If someone commits suicide, their soul goes to hell. It could be that after Father Damien killed himself, Pazuzu acquired his soul and was satisfied.